# link_to rails on click modal should open

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, modal-dialog

I have a link in my application

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> Accept'), {:controller => "dashboard", :action => "accept_bid", :id => bid_det.id }, :class => "btn btn-success incoming_accept_bid", :id => "bid_acc_"+bid_det.id.to_s, :data => {:toggle => "modal", :bidid => bid_det.id.to_s}, :remote => true  %>
```

I have my javascript placed and it is like

```
  $('.incoming_accept_bid').each(function(i) {
    var bid_acc = $(this).data('bidid');
    $('#bid_acc_vin_'+bid_acc).on('click', function(){     
    $('#bid_accept_vin_'+bid_acc).modal(); $('#incoming_bid_det_'+bid_acc).hide(); });
  });
```

On click i'm getting the following error for opening the modal

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /accept_bid/28

I know the error my link_to is converted to

```
<a href="/accept_bid/28" class="btn btn-success incoming_accept_bid" data-bidid="28" data-remote="true" data-toggle="modal" id="bid_acc_28"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> Accept</a>
```

if href is # then it would have worked, but i want to call tha action as well as open the modal on click.

Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: if what you want is make the js function working then add a return false statement at the last of your event handler of click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.incoming_accept_bid').each(function(i) {
    var bid_acc = $(this).data('bidid');
    $('#bid_acc_vin_'+bid_acc).on('click', function(){     
    $('#bid_accept_vin_'+bid_acc).modal(); $('#incoming_bid_det_'+bid_acc).hide(); });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: return false didn't work for .each function so i changed to click function like 
   
    $('.incoming_accept_bid').on('click', function(){     
     var bid_acc = $(this).data('bidid');
    $('#bid_accept_vin_'+bid_acc).modal();        $('#incoming_bid_det_'+bid_acc).hide(); 
    return false;
});

Comment: can you correct my answer, then let the followers know how to do it.